# Name and background information on this space glyph

Tags: symbols, plain-tex, naming

Given the following plain TeX snippet and it's output:

```
hallo werld

{\catcode`\ =12
hallo wereld}

{\tt
hallo wereld}

{\tt\catcode`\ =12
hallo wereld}
```

[image: Screenshot of pdfTeX output on given example]

The command `` \catcode`\ =12 `` changes the category of the space character to "Other". This will make TeX display it.

The space glyph in a typewriter typeface looks familiar. However, the glyph shown in the default typeface I don't recognize.

Out of curiosity, does it have a name? And what is it used for?

Comment: As defined in Unicode, the "open box" glyph in the typewriter corresponds to http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2423/index.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TeX doesn't use a real character from the current font for spaces, so Knuth decided to fill also the slot usually reserved for it with a rarely used glyph: the slash for producing the "Polish suppressed ell" ł. Here are the relevant lines in `plain.tex`

```
\def\l{\char32l}
\def\L{\leavevmode\setbox0\hbox{L}\hbox to\wd0{\hss\char32L}}
```

This is also supplemented by a kerning entry in the TFM file:

```
(LIGTABLE
   (LABEL O 40)
   (KRN C l R -0.277779)
   (KRN C L R -0.319446)
   (STOP)
   ...
```

Since the character has width 0.277779pt, when it comes before a lowercase "l", its width is compensated for.

In the `cmtt10` font (and the other typewriter type fonts), the slot is filled with a "visible space".

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the slash on U+2422 (BLANK SYMBOL): ␢. Since LaTeX has been known to overlay slashes on regular characters (e.g., the symbol produced by `\hbar`), I bet the underlying *b* was erased or omitted.